# Google knowledge graph not properly showing two companies have merged, it shows one aquired the other

Tags: google-search, schema.org, knowledge-graph

My org recently merged with another org. A joint press release was issued and everybody has gone out of their way to stress that this is a merger and not an acquisition. However, when you search for the other org by name in Google, my org is being listed as the "Parent organization" in the Knowledge Graph box on the right. How do I change/remove this? Is it because someone made edits to the other org's Google My Business profile? I couldn't find any schema markup for their website (by viewing their page source) and in ours, nothing of the sort is listed.

Comment: Check https://support.google.com/business/answer/7178589

Comment: Google will take this information from many sources such as Wikipedia, Wikidata, other relevant and reputable sources, etc - you need to make sure you are presenting consistent information to them that it is indeed a "merger" in these locations. Also use the same information in your "about" page and social profiles.